# Why does one version of this Java stream work on a Static Map while the other fails?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've got a static map:

```
private static final Map<SomeObject, AnotherObject> SOME_MAP = ...build map here...
```

I'm trying to generate a single list of type `List<AnotherObject>`

This works as expected:

```
List<AnotherObject> list = Stream.of(SOME_MAP.values())
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The following fails due to non-static method cannot be referenced in static context

```
List<AnotherObject> list = SOME_MAP.values().stream()
  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can anyone explain exactly how the second version is encounting a non-static method error while the first version does not?

Here's a concrete example:

```
private static final Map<Integer, Integer> SOME_MAP = ImmutableMap.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

@Test
public void workingTest() {
 List<Integer> list = Stream.of(SOME_MAP.values())
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

   System.out.println(list); // prints out [2, 4, 6]
}


@Test
public void nonWorkingTest() {
 List<Integer> list = SOME_MAP.values().stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

   System.out.println(list); // Fails before this.
}
```

With the failing test I get the following error:

```
Error:(79, 17) java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
(argument mismatch; invalid method reference
  method stream in interface java.util.Collection<E> cannot be applied to given types
    required: no arguments
    found: java.lang.Integer
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

 Error:(79, 18) java: invalid method reference
    non-static method stream() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: Include the stacktrace. Which method is it referencing?

Comment: the 2nd snippet doesn't need the flatMap

Comment: That is because `Stream.of(T t)` is a static function, where as `Collection::stream` is not static

Comment: your types look wrong. looks like you mean Map<SomeObject, List<AnotherObject>> SOME_MAP or such

Comment: The first version calls `Stream.of(T t)`, where `T` is `Collection<AnotherObject>`, i.e. it creates *"a sequential `Stream` containing a **single** element"*, i.e. a `Stream<Collection<AnotherObject>>`. Not much of a stream. The second version creates a stream of values from the map, i.e. a `Stream<AnotherObject>`. Now that's a good stream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is simple. Both variants are giving back different Streams.

`Stream.of(SOME_MAP.values())` results in a `Stream<Collection<AnotherObject>>`.

On the other hand `SOME_MAP.values().stream()` results in a `Stream<AnotherObject>`. You don't need to call `Stream::flatMap` on it.

Comment: You meant `Stream<Collection<AnotherObject>>`, right?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's correct. I corrected it in my answer.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Assumed they'd have the same result, but see they're not returning the same stream.